# How to show all hours even no data in Firebird?

Tags: date, firebird

I want to write a query that shows all hours (for getting total order) between start date and end date even no data.

Result should be like this:

| count | extract(hour) | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 2020-12-03 |
| 10 | 2 | 2020-12-03 |
| 13 | 3 | 2020-12-03 |
| 0 | 4 | 2020-12-03 |
| 7 | 5 | 2020-12-03 |
| 0 | . | 2020-12-03 |
| 0 | . | 2020-12-03 |
| 0 | . | 2020-12-03 |
| 0 | 23 | 2020-12-03 |

But right now I can get without 0's. Not all of them.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT r.SIRANO), extract (HOUR  from r.Hour),  r.Date
FROM  r
JOIN  r2 ON r.SIRANO = r2.r_SIRANO 
JOIN  s ON s.SIRANO = r2.s_SIRANO 
WHERE r.TARIH BETWEEN DATE '2019-09-18'  AND   DATEADD(DAY, 2, date '2019-09-18')
AND s.ADI = 'Chocolate'
GROUP BY r.Date, extract (HOUR  from r.Hour) 
ORDER BY r.Date, extract (HOUR  from r.Hour);
```

How can i solve it?

Edit: I tried to create an hours table.

```
 create table Hours
 (
  hour_key integer
  );

  Insert Into Hours values
  (0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12),
  (13),(14),(15),(16),(17),(18),(19),(20),(21),(22),(23);
```

And this:

```
SELECT COUNT( r.SIRANO), hour_key,  r.Date 
FROM hours h
Left  JOIN  r  ON h.hour_key= extract (HOUR  from r.Hour)
JOIN  r2 ON r.SIRANO = r2.r_SIRANO 
JOIN  s ON s.SIRANO = r2.STOK_SIRANO 
WHERE r.Date BETWEEN DATE '2019-09-18'  AND   DATEADD(DAY, 2, date 
'2019-09-18')
AND s.ADI = 'Chocolate'
GROUP BY r.Date, hour_key 
ORDER BY r.Date, hour_key;
```

But I get the same result. I can not see 0's in the result.

Edit2: After tried to add

```
SELECT COUNT( r.SIRANO), hour_key,  r.Date 
FROM HOURS h
Left  JOIN  r  ON h.hour_key= extract (HOUR  from r.Hour) AND 
r.Date BETWEEN DATE '2019-09-18'  AND   DATEADD(DAY, 2, date '2019- 
09-18')
LEFT JOIN  r2 ON r.SIRANO = r2.r_SIRANO 
LEFT JOIN  s ON s.SIRANO = r2.s_SIRANO 
AND s.ADI = 'Chocolate'
GROUP BY r.Date, hour_key 
ORDER BY r.Date, hour_key;
```

After this i get 0-23 for first day. But total order numbers are not true.

Comment: Generate synthetic hours table with complete values list (or create such static service table) then leftjoin your data to it.

Comment: I created a hours table as you recommended to me. Then i did left join my data to it, but i get still the same result. I can not see 0 results.

Comment: All joins must be LEFT.

Comment: After all joins left again the same result.

Comment: Move conditions from WHERE to ON clause. They converts LEFT joins to INNER now.